# Cannot assign requested address on instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to host a minecraft network.

In final, I resolved to start a minecraft public server.
But, I have plugins on it that starts webserver.

Problem is here, any Ip I put: Cannot assign requested address
I tryied with 0.0.0.0, internal Ip, external ip and only: Cannot assign requested address machine & IP & all from google cloud.

I'm not sure, but what's do: IP forwarding at google cloud when creating instance? I put it on.